# $P(\liminf S_n)=1$ what does it mean?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

$P(\cdot)$ is the probability measure.

$S_n$ is a sequence of events.

$P(\liminf S_n)=1$  does it mean that $S_n$ always happen after some large n?

Can I say that it must be true that $\liminf P(S_n)=1$ given $P(\liminf S_n)=1$ ?

Comment: Sorry,   $P$ is the probability.     $S_n$ is a sequence of events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $S = \liminf S_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left(\bigcap_{n \ge k} S_n\right)$; saying that $P(S)=1$ means that (almost) all outcomes $\omega$ belong to $S$, that is belong to $\bigcap_{n \ge k} S_n$ for at least one $k$; in other terms, $\omega\in S_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$'s.

In short, this means that that *all* events $S_n$ happen, except for a finite number of them.

Comment: So if I can prove that $P(\liminf S_n)=1$.  Then it implies that $P(S_n)=1$ after some large $n$.  Is it correct?

Comment: Not really. You have (assuming the $S_n$'s are subsets of a probability space $\Omega$) that
$$\forall_{\rm{}a.s.}\omega\in\Omega\exists k\text{ s.t. }\forall n\geq k,\quad \omega\in S_n$$
What you just asked is 
$$\exists k\text{ s.t. } \forall_{\rm{}a.s.}\omega\in\Omega\forall n\geq k,\quad \omega\in S_n$$

Comment: Can I say $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(S_n)=1$ ?(, given $P(\liminf S_n)=1$)?

Since $P(\liminf S_n)=1$, that mean there are infinite consecutive $S_i$ happen together,  I think $P(\liminf S_n)=1$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(s_n)=1$

Comment: This is an implication, yes. Since $T_k=\cap_{n \ge k} S_n$ is non-decreasing,
$$P \left( \cup_{k \geq 1} \cap_{n \ge k} S_n \right) = \lim_k P \left( \cap_{n \ge k} S_n \right) \le \lim_k \inf_{n \ge k} P(S_n).$$
(can also be proven with Fatou's lemma) and since the LHS is $1$ by assumption, you get $ \lim_k \inf_{n \ge k} P(S_n) = 1$ which implies here that $P(S_n)\to 1$.

Comment: Fantastic! This is just what i need.   Thanks